# Debian CLI Install to Flash Drive

Tags: linux, debian, command-line-interface

I'm installing Debian linux command-line-only onto a flash drive for portability, and I'd like some direction if you can offer it. After the base install, I can boot from the thumb drive perfectly, and it loads the command prompt. Now, there's specific things that I'd like to be able to do, and I'm not sure what packages I need to do so.

I want to be able to have several different command lines open at once (so that, for example, if I'm coding a server/clients application, I can run a server in one CLI, and several clients in the subsequent CLI's). I believe Ubuntu offers something like this, with CTRL+ALT+F1 - CTRL+ALT+F7. Is there any way I can do something similar in my situation?

Other than that, I'd like to install an internet browser. Will I need a full-blown graphical environment to handle that? If not, what will I need?

Currently I have only installed the XORG package.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is on-topic on superuser.com. I've flagged for a move there.

Comment: Thank you. I've never heard of superuser.com, I agree that this question fits better there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A Debian install should already have Virtual Terminals [The Ctrl+Alt+Fx]. The number of terminals available is usually set in `/etc/inittab`. But consider installing '[GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)' and [learning how to use it](http://devcheatsheet.com/tag/screen/). It is very nifty.
2. There is the possibility of using a text-only browser, like '[ELinks](http://elinks.or.cz/)'. OR, you could install and configure a simple [window manager](http://wiki.debian.org/WindowManager), and then install a browser, like [iceweasel](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/iceweasel). While you're at it, you might also install '[xterm](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/xterm)' so you can open up terminals from your X session.

Comment: @nct25 - If this (and any other answer) answers your question correctly, consider marking it 'correct'. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is how you do it.